# jQuery if url hash, click event/activate javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

So from the home page, i have a link that goes to a products listing page.
The product page has expand/collapse divs.

I need the appropriate div to expand depending on what the url# is.

So the link on the homepage is

```
<a href="/out-products.php#healthysnacks">healthy snacks</a>
```

when i click the link above, i am trying to activate this, on the product page:

```
<a href="javascript:ReverseDisplay('products4')" id="healthysnacks"> Healthy Snacks</a>
```

I've tried some of the other codes that i found that trigger click by checking for hash tag and none of them were working properly, i think it's because of the ReverseDisplay js.
Please any insight would help.

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make the following changes in the document ready function of your product page:

**Simple fix:** Since the jQuery id-selector is `#elementId`, you can simply use the `window.location.hash` value as your id selector, and use it to target the desired element.

```
if ( window.location.hash ) {
    $(window.location.hash).click(); //clicks on element specified by hash
}
```

**Better:** In addition to the above, take the js out of your markup.

```
$('#healthysnacks').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ReverseDisplay('products4');
});
```

Then, *after doing this*, use the `$(window.location.hash).click()` code from above.
Also, change your link to:

```
<a href="#" id="healthysnacks"> Healthy Snacks</a>
```

Comment: @raminson `window.location.hash` gives a string, in this case containing '#healthysnacks' so it works as an id selector. I probably should clarify that in the post though, thanks

Comment: Yes, you are correct, i had forgotten that hash property returns the # sign too.

Comment: @alex Have you included jQuery in the page? `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: its an older site, i have 1.5.1, let me upgrade :)

Comment: the first banner on the accordion, click the text, it links to what i'm needing

Comment: @alex Ah okay, I understand your problem now. Try the updated code (the `window.location.hash` value was changing before the code ran). Should be fine now. p.s. you should probably change your other links to work like this as well (just give them all the same class-name like `class='links'` and then change the selector for the click from `'#healthysnacks'` to `'.links'`)

Comment: im still having no luck. do you need any other info?

Comment: You pasted them in the wrong order... you have to define the click handler before you call `.click()`

Comment: :::facepalm::: my bad, i just pasted in the order it was provided. thanks a lot for your help, very appreciated!

Comment: @alex No problem, I should have specified. I wasn't sure if you were going to use the second part, that's why I put them in that order

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `hash` property of the `Location` object, try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var id = window.location.hash;
   $(id).trigger('click')
})
```

As you are using jQuery instead of using `javascript:` protocol, you can use the jQuery `click` method:

```
$('#healthysnacks').click(function() {
   // do something here
})
```

Comment: nice solution, works perfect for my setup. Are there any probable security flaws associated with this? somewhere else I saw some regex sanitization for this kind of has usage..

Answer (score 3):

The answers suggested here are valid, but...

Be extremely careful when using the window.location.hash as it is in a jQuery selector because  this could lead to a XSS vulnerability. $() can also create an HTML element and with a carefully constructed hash value, someone could execute arbitrary JavaScript code.

For example

`http://my-website.com/about#'><img src=x onerror=alert(/XSSed/)>`

If my-websites.com/about page uses the window.location.hash inside a jQuery selector, that onerror code would end up getting executed.