# jquery show/hide Div with direct link

Tags: jquery, css, hyperlink, hide, show

Kidnly help me to finish it :)

So i have this kind of simple SHOW/HIDE content with [jquery](http://jsfiddle.net/fKGc5/110/), but problem is getting it shown with direct link.

works simple, like i like. But i need some way to show it with example.php#div1 or example.php#div2

Any suggestion?

```
e.preventDefault();
var targetDiv = $($(this).attr('href'));
if(!targetDiv.is(':visible')){
    $('.page').slideUp();
    targetDiv.slideDown();
}else{
    $('.page').slideUp();
}
```

});

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show `example.php`. Both div1 and div2. I'm not sure what you're referring to. Your question is also very vague. What do you mean "getting it shown with direct link"?

Comment: @Nicolas I believe Aleksandr means to trigger a click event on the hashbang value in the URI. An elegant/simple example seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11895681/jquery-if-url-hash-click-event-activate-javascript

Duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for.  But you can add a hash listener

[onhashchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onhashchange)

Here is a fiddle that I created that looks at the hash part of the url rather than listening to the click event.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fKGc5/113/)

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", function(){    
    var targetDiv = $(location.hash);
    console.log(targetDiv);
    if(!targetDiv.is(':visible')){
        $('.page').slideUp();
        targetDiv.slideDown();
    }else{
        $('.page').slideUp();
    }
}, false);
```

I'm not sure if this will fire on the first load, but on the load event you can check for location.hash to see if one exists.

Comment: Yeah, looks exactly what i need! Cheers!

Comment: Just noticed one thing, whn it comes to hidden div height over 100px and DIV1 is opened, you're clicking to open DIV2 is works... well not so "pretty" is there any chance to make it work. So once you click another DIV to open it first closing opened one and than opening next one?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in pure CSS. This example uses a slide from left transition. You could change the `translate` transform or use another property like `opacity` for another effect, or just change the `display` property for no animation.

HTML:

```
<a href="#div1">Show div1</a>
<div id="div1">1</div>

<a href="#div2">Show div2</a>
<div id="div2">2</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  transform: translate(-200px);
  transition: transform 400ms ease;
}

div:target {
  transform: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jwhitfieldseed/xf76pgt0/

Comment: Yeah, looks like what i need, but there is one problem square is fixed and each having it's place, so in ma case of having 4 DIVS are are transporent, but not hidden...

Answer (score 0):

Send get parameter in url for example

```
example.php?div_to_hide=1
```

and in javascript do this

```
var targetDiv = $('#div<?php echo isset($_GET['div_to_hide']) ? $_GET['div_to_hide'] : "" ?>');
```

Comment: php is what i have right now, but it's not exit, i'm trying to do it with jquery...